# Correlation Matrix Question

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, monte-carlo

Why is this not a possible correlation matrix for any three random variables X, Y, and Z?

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1\\ -1 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: If $|Cov(X,Y)|=\sqrt{Var(X) Var(Y)}$ then $X$ is a scalar multiple of $Y$ (this is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality). This occurs here for each of $X,Y,Z$. What happens?

Comment: So $X$ = $X*Y$ which is impossible with a correlation of -1?

Comment: this one is indefinite. Should be positive semi-definite

Comment: Why do correlation matrices need to be PSD?

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y are perfectly negatively correlated and Y and Z are perfectly negatively correlated then X and Z must be perfectly positively correlated.

Think about a graph of X being dots on a straight line with gradient 1 and Y being dots on a straight line with gradient -1. Both of these cannot have corr -1 with a 3rd variable.